# 'mv' command throwing error but executing fine in docker

Tags: bash, ubuntu, docker

When I execute the following command (which moves all files with the `.txt` and `.sbreaks` extension to another folder):

```
sudo docker exec name mv xyz/data/outputs/*.{sbreaks,txt} <>/data/spare
```

I get the following error:

```
mv: cannot stat ‘xyz/data/outputs/*.sbreaks’: No such file or directory
mv: cannot stat ‘xyz/data/outputs/*.txt’: No such file or directory
```

But, when I go into docker via `sudo docker exec -it name bash` and execute the same command: `mv xyz/data/outputs/*.{sbreaks,txt} xyz/data/spare`, it executes fine.

What am I doing wrong here?

PS: Both local and the Docker container are ubuntu environments

Comment: What is `<>` representing?

Comment: @Whymarrh Edited with the proper name

Answer (score 10, accepted):

That is because the `*` is expanded by a shell program (i.e. bash). (Psst, this is typical interview question).

So pass your command to a shell and let it launch the `mv` for you:

```
sudo docker exec cypher bash -c 'mv xyz/data/outputs/*.{sbreaks,txt} .......'
```

When you do `docker exec some_program some_param`, docker searches for `some_program` and executes it directly without doing anything extra, and just pass `some_param` as a parameter (a star in your case). `mv` expects real file names, and not `*`.

Comment: TIL.  Thanks a lot :)